# See segmentation fault running tensorflow.contrib.learn tutorial example

Tags: tensorflow, segmentation-fault

See segmentation faults when running the `tf.contrib.learn` example shown in tensorflow official tutorial `https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/get_started`.

The tutorial example code is

```
import tensorflow as tf
# NumPy is often used to load, manipulate and preprocess data.
import numpy as np

# Declare list of features. We only have one real-valued feature. There are many
# other types of columns that are more complicated and useful.
features = [tf.contrib.layers.real_valued_column("x", dimension=1)]

# An estimator is the front end to invoke training (fitting) and evaluation
# (inference). There are many predefined types like linear regression,
# logistic regression, linear classification, logistic classification, and
# many neural network classifiers and regressors. The following code
# provides an estimator that does linear regression.
estimator = tf.contrib.learn.LinearRegressor(feature_columns=features)

# TensorFlow provides many helper methods to read and set up data sets.
# Here we use `numpy_input_fn`. We have to tell the function how many     batches
# of data (num_epochs) we want and how big each batch should be.
x = np.array([1., 2., 3., 4.])
y = np.array([0., -1., -2., -3.])
input_fn = tf.contrib.learn.io.numpy_input_fn({"x":x}, y, batch_size=4,
                                              num_epochs=1000)

# We can invoke 1000 training steps by invoking the `fit` method and passing the
# training data set.
estimator.fit(input_fn=input_fn, steps=1000)

# Here we evaluate how well our model did. In a real example, we would want
# to use a separate validation and testing data set to avoid overfitting.
estimator.evaluate(input_fn=input_fn)
```

Observed segmentation fault:

```
WARNING:tensorflow:Using temporary folder as model directory: /tmp/user/71201/tmpr6SZQb
WARNING:tensorflow:Rank of input Tensor (1) should be the same as output_rank     (2) for column. Will attempt to expand dims. It is highly recommended that you resize your input, as this behavior may change.
WARNING:tensorflow:From /mypath/venv/tensor/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/head.py:1362: scalar_summary (from tensorflow.python.ops.logging_ops) is deprecated and will be removed after 2016-11-30.
Instructions for updating:
Please switch to tf.summary.scalar. Note that tf.summary.scalar uses the node name instead of the tag. This means that TensorFlow will automatically de-duplicate summary names based on the scope they are created in. Also, passing a tensor or list of tags to a scalar summary op is no longer supported.
WARNING:tensorflow:Rank of input Tensor (1) should be the same as output_rank     (2) for column. Will attempt to expand dims. It is highly recommended that you resize your input, as this behavior may change.
WARNING:tensorflow:From /mypath/venv/tensor/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/head.py:1362: scalar_summary (from tensorflow.python.ops.logging_ops) is deprecated and will be removed after 2016-11-30.
Instructions for updating:
Please switch to tf.summary.scalar. Note that tf.summary.scalar uses the node name instead of the tag. This means that TensorFlow will automatically de-duplicate summary names based on the scope they are created in. Also, passing a tensor or list of tags to a scalar summary op is no longer supported.
WARNING:tensorflow:Skipping summary for global_step, must be a float or np.float32.
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Environments and versions:

```
python2.7
#tensor Installed from source
cd tensorflow && git rev-parse HEAD
286a5361df528dd5d5f1c5b319a69a0029e245bc

python -c "import tensorflow; print(tensorflow.__version__)"
1.0.0

lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS
Release:        14.04
Codename:       trusty
```